# How can I know if fsck was performed on the operating system partition?

Tags: fsck

I use to order `fsck` by doing:

```
# touch /forcefsck
```

On **Ubuntu Linux v14** I have found this method to check if, after rebooting, it was performed:

```
luis@Terminus:~$ sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda7 | grep "mount" -i
dumpe2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Last mounted on:          /
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Last mount time:          Sun Feb 28 23:24:18 2016
Mount count:              1
Maximum mount count:      -1
```

The trick is in the `Mount count` data: it is supposed to tell the **number of times** the partition has been **mounted** after the last check. So a number of `1` after rebooting means it was just checked right now.

But on **Kali Linux v2.0** it seems **not** to be working all right. This is the result after the same `touch /forcefsck` command:

```
luis@Midnighter:~$ sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sdb8 | grep "mount" -i
dumpe2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
Last mounted on:          /
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Last mount time:          Sun Feb 28 21:22:49 2016
Mount count:              82
Maximum mount count:      -1
```

How could I confirm `fsck` was performed?

Answer (score 1):

There's a direct way of telling when fsck was last run on the filesystem:

```
tune2fs -l /dev/sdb8 | grep '^Last checked:'
```

(or `dumpe2fs` instead of `tune2fs -l`.)

On Debian, the presence of `/forcefsck` causes the boot scripts to run `fsck -f` instead of `fsck`, which forces a filesystem check (normally `fsck` just says that the filesystem is clean and exits immediately). I don't know if Kali Linux has changed the relevant script (`/etc/init.d/checkroot.sh` on a SysVinit system).

Comment: Indeed, at Kali  the `forcefsck` trick does not work. I have finally succeded with this method based on mounting the root partition as read-only, reboot, fsck, reboot and remount as read-write again: http://bitsofmymind.com/2014/03/14/how-to-fix-fsck-your-root-file-system-that-you-have-to-boot-into-on-linux/ . Tested working via SSH.

Comment: It is hard to believe that there is no easy/quick way to check your root file system on Linux. Even Windows can do it via `chkdsk /f`.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez why do you think you should want to check the root file system?